# memory usage + performance when using visible vs add / remove from stage

Tags: performance, apache-flex, memory

Is there a performance and/or memory usage difference between these two scenarios?

scenario 1: N visual elements all added to stage; N-1 have visible = false, 1 has visible = true;

scenario 2: N visual elements, only 1 added to the stage at any time.

thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Visible = false` is far faster.

[Colin Moock has weighed in on this issue in a definitive manner](http://www.developria.com/2008/11/visible-false-versus-removechi.html). 
His findings:

> 10000 removeChild() calls took 300ms, whereas 10000 visible
>   assignments took 7ms.

His basic guidelines are :

- `removeChild()` - for predictable control of the display list, add and remove.
- `visible=false` - for straight up performance, `visible` is clearly faster;

As far as "predictability" is concerned, we often use the display list as a stack to identify and control display objects. If you are leveraging visibility, you loose that state (which can be a big deal). Conclusively, though, if performance is required the winner is clear.

I realize your post is directed at Flex but I think, in this case, we're talking the behavior of an SWF and so flex/flash shouldn't matter.